# UNIX Shell Scripting Problem on command "r--" command not found

Tags: linux, shell, unix

i think the if statement is comparing the command to the text instead of the output of the command, any tips or help to fix this simple problem

i made this code so far:

```
    #!/bin/bash
echo -n "Enter File Name: "
read file

#Permission for the User Date
[ -w $file ] && W="yes" || W="No"

[ -x $file ] && X="yes" || W="No"

[ -r $file ] && R="yes" || R="No"

#Permission for the Group Data

grt= `ls -l $file | cut -c5-7`

if [ "grt" = "---" ]

 then

  grp="No No No"

elif [ "$grt" = "r--" ]

 then

  grp=" Yes No No"

elif [ "$grt" = "-w-" ]

 then

  grp="No Yes No"

elif [ "$grt" = "--x" ]

 then

  grp="No No Yes"

elif [ "$grt" = "rw-" ]

 then

  grp="Yes Yes No"

elif [ "$grt" = "r-x" ]

 then

  grp="Yes No Yes" 

elif [ "$grt" = "-wx" ]

 then

  grp="No Yes Yes"

fi

#Output

echo

echo "$file Properties"

echo

echo "        Read Write Execute"

echo "User:    $R   $W     $X"

echo "Group:   $grp"
```

Answer (score 3):

You [shouldn't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Use `stat` instead, if you have it. See [BashFAQ/087](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/087) for information on getting file metadata.

You can replace all those `if` / `elif` statements with a `case` statement.

```
case "$grt" in
    "---") grp="No  No  No";;
    "r--") grp="Yes No  No";;
    . . .
esac
```

or you can map strings and do it all in just two statements (no `if`, no `case`):

```
grp=${grt//[rwx]/Yes }    # change any "r", "w" or "x" to "Yes "
grp=${grp//-/No  }         # change any "-" to "No  "
```

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be a space after the `grt=`, i.e.

```
grt= `ls -l $file | cut -c5-7`
```

instead of the correct

```
grt=`ls -l $file | cut -c5-7`
```

This makes bash setting the variable grt to the empty string and executing the result of the command in backticks.

Not related to your question, but maybe important for what you are going to do: The -r, -w, -x tests are *not* the user part of the user/group/other rights, but test whether the current user is able to read (write, ...) this file.

Comment: Great! you really Helped me, now i know what to do

Comment: @Pocari: If this is the answer that helped you, you should generally mark it as "accepted answer" - so cebewee would get its credits for helping ;)